# A Metaphysical Question: A Real or Nonexistent Line?

Tags: metaphysics

Who, among the many philosophers, might be regarded as notable believers in what might be called a unitary point of view regarding our universe (e.g. no existing line of division between the material and spiritual worlds)?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Philosophy SE. Please visit our [Help Center](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help) to see what questions we answer and how to ask. One-line posts are discouraged because it is hard to tell from them what people are looking for. As it is, your question is so general and vague that it is better addressed by reading online encyclopedias on philosophical [non-dualism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondualism) and [monism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monism) than asking here, we are focusing on more specific and pointed questions.

Comment: read about non-dualism and monism.

Answer (score 1):

Such a unitary view is named **monism**. In general, adherents of monism face the problem to reduce one type of entities, either the material or the spiritual entities, to the other type.

A monistic position, which considers fundamental the spiritual entities, is Advaita-Vedanta. Shankara, the main proponent of this type of monism, considers real the spiritual world and an illusion the material entitities, i.e. the physical world.

A opposite monistic position is taken by d'Holbach, who considers fundamental the physical entities. d'Holbach considers our mental capabilities as properties of our physical components.

A third alternative of monism would be to consider both types of entities resulting from a third, fundamental type of entity.

You find more on the different variants in https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/monism/

IMO, it is very difficult to explain the multitude of phenomena by a monistic approach. I am not convinced by any proposed monistic model. Instead I tend to the view: We need at least two irreducible concepts, one being a concept from physics like energy, the other one a concept from information theory like the concept of information. Both types of entities interact by a series of processes.

Comment: I feel it is important to distinguish between monism and nondualism, the latter being the 'advaita' reading of the late Vedas. Your last paragraph notes the problem. Monism doesn't work. We would have to go beyond the idea of a numerical 'One' to solve the problems of monism. The 'Unity' or 'Unicity' spoken of by Perennialists is not a numerical one.

Comment: @PeterJ In which respect do you consider a difference between "advaita = non-dualism" and "monism"?

Comment: 'Ad-vaita' translates as 'not-two' and is a deliberate avoidance of the term 'One'. This view rejects both dualism and monism. Your criticism of monism seems correct to me but the idea the world is a Unity is not monism. It is non-dualism. This is imho one of the most important issues in all of philosophy. If we confuse advaita Vedanta, Taoism, Buddhism, Sufism etc. with monism then they will seem to make no sense and to provide no solutions for metaphysics. If we can see the difference between monism and non-dualism then we have a grasp of the metaphysical foundation of mysticism. . .